# basic Haskell : searching through multiple lists for the same elements

Tags: haskell

I've been battling with this problem for a while. I'm trying to create an "organisation" which is a list of Gyms. These gyms are a list of People. Each person has an ID number, an age and an amount of credit.

I want the FindID function to search through the organisation to search through the list of Gyms to find the users with the inputted ID and then return the total of their credit. However, I feel I'm overcomplcating the problem and I am really struggling now.

```
newtype ID = ID Int deriving (Show)
newtype Age = Age Int deriving (Show)
newtype Credit = Credit Int deriving (Show)
newtype Person = Person (ID, Age, Weight) deriving (Show)   
type Gym = [Person]
type Organisation = [Gym]


getAge :: Person -> Int
getAge (Person(a,Age b,c)) = b

getID :: Person -> Int
getID (Person(ID a,b,c)) = a

getCredit :: Person -> Int
getCredit (Person(a,b,Credit c)) = c

p = Person ( ID 123, Age 65, Credit 12000)
q = Person ( ID 321, Age 64, Credit 0)
e = Person ( ID 453, Age 30, Credit 3000)
r = Person ( ID 123, Age 65, Credit 2310)
s = Person ( ID 364, Age 32, Credit 32340)
t = Person ( ID 123, Age 65, Credit 1300)
org1 = [p,q,e]
org2 = [r,s,t]


hasPerson :: Gym->Int-> Bool
hasPerson gym' id' = not (null(filter hasperson' gym') )
    where 
         hasperson' person' = getID person' == id'

findID:: ID -> Organisation -> Int
findID id' org = total
    where
         IsInGym org' = hasPerson ( org' id' )
         validGym =  filter (IsInGym) org'
         total = sum ( map getCredit validGym)
```

Comment: I'm quite sure this code doesn't compile. E.g. how are `validGym` and `market'` defined?

Comment: Sorry, I copied the code from a different example and I forgot to change it when putting it here. Changed now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I would recommend using a record to represent your person, unless you have a particular reason to assign a new type to each field:

```hs
type ID = Int
type Age = Int
type Credit = Int
data Person = Person
    { personId :: ID
    , personAge :: Age
    , personCredit :: Credit
    } deriving (Eq, Show)

type Gym = [Person]
type Organization = [Gym]
```

Next, you can use `map` to convert a `Gym` into `[Int]` with `personId`, then you can use the built-in `elem` to check if the ID given appears in that list.

```hs
hasPerson :: Gym -> ID -> Bool
hasPerson gym pId = pId `elem` map personId gym
```

Now, for the `findID` function, I would suggest renaming it to something like `organizationCredit`, and I would make a simpler function called `gymCredit` to calculate it for a single gym:

```hs
gymCredit :: ID -> Gym -> Credit
gymCredit pId gym = sum $ map personCredit $ filter (\p -> personId p == pId) gym

organizationCredit :: ID -> Organization -> Credit
organizationCredit pId org = sum $ map (gymCredit pId) org
```

Alternatively, you could declare your functions as

```hs
gymCredit :: Person -> Gym -> Credit
gymCredit person gym = sum $ map personCredit $ filter (\p -> personId p == pId) gym
    where pId = personId person

organizationCredit :: Person -> Organization -> Credit
organizationCredit person org = sum $ map (gymCredit person) org
```

**EDIT**: To stick with your old types, you just have to define a few extra functions yourself, then put them in your code where you need to

```hs
newtype ID = ID Int deriving (Eq, Show)
newtype Age = Age Int deriving (Eq, Show)
newtype Credit = Credit Int deriving (Eq, Show)
newtype Person = Person (ID, Age, Credit) deriving (Eq, Show)
type Gym = [Person]
type Organisation = [Gym]

personId :: Person -> ID
personId (Person (i, a, c)) = i

personAge :: Person -> Age
personAge (Person (i, a, c)) = a

personCredit :: Person -> Credit
personCredit (Person (i, a, c)) = c

idVal :: ID -> Int
idVal (ID x) = x

ageVal :: Age -> Int
ageVal (Age x) = x

creditVal :: Credit -> Int
creditVal (Credit x) = x

gymCredit :: Person -> Gym -> Credit
gymCredit person gym = Credit $ sum $ map (creditVal . personCredit) $ filter (\p -> personId p == pId) gym
    where pId = personId person

organisationCredit :: Person -> Organisation -> Credit
organisationCredit person org = Credit $ sum $ map (creditVal . gymCredit person) org
```

It is important to note that I've added `Eq` to the list of derived typeclasses for each newtype.  Without it, you wouldn't be able to directly compare two `ID`s, you'd have to extract the values first.  Another important typeclass to derive is `Ord`, which lets you use the `<`, `>`, `<=`, and `>=` operators, as well as a whole bunch of list functions like `sort`.

Comment: The lambda could be written as `(pId ==) . personId`.

Comment: @Philipp It can, and I would use that in my code, but the lambda function is arguably easier to understand for a beginner

Comment: Wow! Thanks a lot this looks really promising but can you explain what this line does please:
(\p -> personId p == pId)
It obviously compares p with pID and returns a boolean but what does the \p -> personId do?

Comment: the syntax `\args -> expr` is called a lambda function.  It's pretty much just an in-line, nameless function.  It defines a function that takes a single argument `p` and passes it to the expression `personId p == pId`.  One thing to always remember is that function application is higher precedence than operator application, so the expression `personId p == pId` is the same as `(personId p) == pId`.  It isn't comparing `p` to `pId`, it's comparing `personId p` to `pId`.

Comment: Sorry, I'm still having problems. I can't change my initial types without destroying my other functions that I have written. Is there any way I can stick with newtype?